# Air Canada: will there be accommodation compensation for missed connection due to fault of airline?

Tags: airlines, connecting-flights, compensation

I am flying from Toronto to Auckland with a 2 hour transfer in Vancouver. Both flights are bought on the same ticket from Air New Zealand (from 3rd party website), therefore I am not worried about getting to my final destination. The Toronto to Vancouver leg is operated by Air Canada, and the Vancouver to Auckland leg by Air New Zealand. In my experience with Air Canada, there have been many flight delays, and the Vancouver to Auckland leg flies once daily, so a missed connection would mean an overnight stay.

I know that for missed connections due to delays that were not within the control of the airline, there will be no compensation for accommodation. But what if the delay was caused by Air Canada? Their compensation page did not talk about connections, does this mean there is no protection? Also can I find anywhere a standard list of scenarios which count as delays caused by the airline?

Comment: The rights and obligations of both the airline and you are spelled out in the contract you agreed to when you bought the tickets, commonly known as the Conditions of Carriage or Contract of Carriage, which you should be able to find on the Air Canada website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, for missed connections within Air Canada's control departing from Canada, Air Canada will cover overnight hotel accommodations if necessary, plus pay a modest (but adequate) meal allowance.  I had this happen a couple of years ago flying from YQR to FLL via YYZ and YUL.  Our last flight was cancelled, so Air Canada put us up in Montreal.

If the late flight is due to weather or some issue beyond Air Canada's control (and understand that a plane coming late into Toronto due to bad weather elsewhere would count for this), you will be on your own for accommodations and meals unless you paid extra for Air Canada's [On My Way](https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home/plan/peace-of-mind/on-my-way.html) product, which picks up these expenses.